# Count the number of rows returned by the query

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to count the number of queries returned by this specific query on this table.

Postgres - 14

Table `messages`:

| conv_id | user_id | content | sent_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 1st_msg | 01-01-1990 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 002 | 2nd_msg | 02-01-1990 00:00:00 |

database to fiddle - [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cbfe8cdb17bcb1da0af591afb625040e)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id)
       *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id,     user_id, sent_time;
```

If I try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM messages IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id)
           *
    FROM   messages
    ORDER  BY date_trunc('day', sent_time),
    conv_id, user_id, sent_time)
```

it throws an error:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IN" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages IN`

Comment: Number of queries? The query doesn't return queries, methinks. Perhaps use your query as a subqueriy in a query that calculates `count(*)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this is throwing me error

```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages IN


(SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id)
       *
FROM   messages
ORDER  BY date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id, sent_time)```

Comment: `select count(*) from ( ... your query... ) x`

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts. [ask] [answer] [Help]